Original text about Riesel numbers?
Riesel numbers appeared in the answer to my question
Solving $2^{x+1} m -1=p^y$ for prime $p$ and natural $x,y$.
The original reference

Riesel, Hans (1956). "Några stora primtal". Elementa. 39: 258–260

on them appears to be rather hard to find, it's not on AMS' Mathscinet or on ZBMath.
R.Guy's book "Unsolved problems in number theory" does not list it in its references to Riesel's work, instead giving a book by Riesel, where I cannot find the relevant data.
Does anyone have access to this short paper in the "Elementa", an education-oriented magazine which stopped publications long time ago? I'd like to be able to check the original paper before citing it.

many libraries have this journal, I would check out the one closest to you: https://search.worldcat.org/title/609709561

it's rather unclear where the right volumes are available. I ended up doing an inter-library loan request.

I would mention tha construction of Riesel numbers follows immediately (but surely is not mentioned by the author) from the proof of Theorem 3 in Erdos’s paper from 1950:  https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1950-07.pdf

(I have insufficient status to just comment). You can see https://oeis.org/A050412 which links to the English translation of the work. Added within the past month or so.
